# Is there an alternative to using RoleProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider

I'm working on an application where a user can be in one two 'groups' of users (teachers and students). For my needs, a user will never need to be moved from one role to another. While I certainly could create a custom `RoleProvider`, it seems a bit overblown for what I need.

Up to this point, I've been using a modified version of the `MembershipService` that is generated by Visual Studio: I created the function `IsTeacher(IPrincipal user)` which in turn queries my `MembershipProvider`. This solution works well enough in controllers, but it falls short in views (I can do it, it just feels clumsy/smells bad).

How would I best go about creating a class that would let me determine if a user is a teacher from a view? Alternatively, am I over-thinking this and would be fine writing a `RoleProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Are your views strongly-typed?  Seems you could use a ViewModel to pass appropriate user-related information from the controller to the view as boolean properties.

[ViewModel Pattern Example 1](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)

[ViewModel Pattern Example 2](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/)